# How to get the ID of a button created dynamically when it is clicked? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I created a table with buttons with different IDs like below:

```
                ButtonEdit.Text = "Edit"
                ButtonEdit.ID = OrderID
                TBLCell.Controls.Add(ButtonEdit)

                TBLCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
                TBLCell.Width = 100
                TBLCell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
                TBLCell.BorderWidth = 1
                TBLRow.Cells.Add(TBLCell)
                TBLCell = New TableCell
```

But when I click one of these buttons I want to get the Id in :

```
If IsPostBack = True Then

// here i want to get id

end if
```

But, how to get the Id for the selected button?

Comment: In the Click event handler you can cast the sender object to your button and access the ID: `DirectCast(sender, YourButtonEditClass).ID`

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.tco_orders_mv_planning_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check the `IsPostback` property, i assume thar you're doing it in `Page_Load`. Instead use the `Click` event of the `Button`(it's always a postback). Use `AddHandler` to add an event handler dynamically:

```
ButtonEdit.Text = "Edit"
ButtonEdit.ID = OrderID
AddHandler ButtonEdit.Click, AddressOf ButtonEdit_Click
TBLCell.Controls.Add(ButtonEdit)
```

Now you can implement the event handler and use the `sender`-argument to get your button:

```
Private Sub ButtonEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ButtonEdit As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim OrderID As String = ButtonEdit.ID
    ' ... '
End Sub
```

Remember that you have to recreate dynamically created controls on overy postback(in `Page_Load` at the latest)  with the same ID as before.